# Why is a Knapsack problem not an LP problem?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, knapsack-problems

We know that LP can solve optimization problems that have linear constraints and linear objective functions.

A knapsack problem can be formulated into a linear objective function (because it is just a summation of Pi*Xi) and linear constraints (because it is just a summation of the items weights which should be <= the knapsack weight), so why can't we consider it an LP problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up the knapsack problem as an integer linear program: To each item associate a 1/0 variable (include/exclude that item). Setting up the restrictions and the objective function from here is straightforward.

The point here is that the variables are restricted to be *integers*, while (regular) linear programming assumes *real* variables. They look similar, but are quite different beasts, computationally.

One successful technique to construct an *approximate* solution to the knapsack problem makes up a (continuous) linear programming problem, solve that one and tweaks the resulting values.